Cannot receive Prefill value on an OmniScript from LWC
I have two OmniScripts which are being called from LWC with template if and else condition. I am checking a variable inside a code, if the value of the variable is true, OmniScript 1 is getting called and if the value of variable is false, OmniScript 2 is is getting called. Prefill value is same for both the calls and it holds the correct values.
HTML
    <template>
       <template if:true={variable}>
          <c-omni-script-1 layout="lightning" prefill={prefill}></c-omni-script-1>
       </template>
      <template if:false={variable}>      
          <c-omni-script-2="lightning" prefill={prefill}></c-omni-script-2> 
       </template>     
    </template>

in JS:
var osInputObj = new Object();      
osInputObj.UID= '123456';
osInputObj.DNS= dnsId;      
this.prefill =  JSON.stringify(osInputObj) ;

The issue is, I am getting prefill values correctly on omni-script-1 where as the prefill values are null on the omni-script-2. Is there an OmniScript level setting which is missing to receive data from LWCs?

Are you sure this is the code that is actually running?  this can't won't compile, so either you've copied it into this question wrong, or there's something wrong with your setup.  Please edit your question to clarify

Try:
var osInputObj = new Object();  var UID = new Object(); var DNS = new Object(); var dnsId = "123";     osInputObj.UID= '123456';     osInputObj.DNS= dnsId;           this.prefill =  JSON.stringify(osInputObj); 
